# Accessing class property via this in an event call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I'm trying to acces a class property via 'this' in a callback function of an onClick event, but there is a scope-issue and the property isn't defined.

I've tried a couple of setups, but I think I'm just hitting myself in my confusion more than anything.

```js
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.myProperty = "myValue"
    }

    onElementClicked = (event, other, parameters) => {
        console.log(this.myProperty) //Undefined.
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SubElement click={this.onElementClicked} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function SubElement({ click }) {
    const number = "Click me", other = null, parameters = null;
    return (
        <p>
            <span onClick={e => click(e, other, parameters)}>    
                    {number}
            </span>
        </p>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyClass />,
    document.querySelector("main")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main>Please enable JS</main>
```

Comment: It should be `click={this.onElementClicked}` or `click={(e, o, p) => this.onElementClicked(e, o, p)}`. I don't know where you were getting the `undefined` from, but the line with the `console.log` wasn't even executing.

Comment: @Bergi fair comment, I used the wrong code as example. Corrected it now.

Comment: I fixed some syntax issues, but your code works - try the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for methods as they are attached to the object **instance** instead of the class **prototype**, which defeats [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Replace the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with a regular function with the [method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) syntax. Also, `bind` the function to `this` before passing it as prop, otherwise it will be "detached" from the class:

```
export default class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.myProperty = "myValue"
        this.onElementClicked = this.onElementClicked.bind(this);
    }

    onElementClicked(event, other, parameters) {
        console.log(this.myProperty) // Works.
    }
    
   render() {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <div>
                <subElement click={this.onElementClicked}/>
            </div>
        )}
    }
}
```

Comment: Embedding a method call in an arrow function is pretty much equivalent to putting the arrow function in a class field. While I agree that it's generally a bad idea, you typically don't want to inherit from React components.

Comment: The code above allows at least to instantiate the method only once as opposed to once per component instance, which is better in terms of memory consumption and respect of the prototypal inheritance.

Comment: …and then continues to create a new `(...args) => this.onElementClicked(...args)` function every time the `render` method is called, which happens far more often than creating the instance. This is actually worse than instantiating it once per instance.

Comment: Edited with a `bind` in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. However, your answer still doesn't explain why the OP's code didn't work

Comment: Now you fixed it I have no idea, I guess it was the `return` missing from `render` and the missing `extends React.Component`. It makes no sense answering a fixed question though.